# Can't see special characters and emoji

Tags: java, intellij-idea, utf-8, special-characters

I switched from SDK 16.0.2 to OpenJDK 20.0.1 and I can't see any special characters:

[image: output characters]

Instead of them I see "?" characters. I've tried change whole project Encoding to UTF-8 and still no success. I'd like to know what to do.

```
public class Main  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello ěš  ");
}
```

}

Here is my file encoding:

[image: file encoding]

I tried to write into the console something with special characters, but I got a message full of question marks.

Comment: See where exactly? What are you doing?

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: I mean in terminal I cant see the characters.

Comment: Please check and update your question with the following settings: `Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Font`, `Preferences | Advanced Settings | Terminal -> Terminal character encoding`, `Preferences | Tools | Terminal -> Shell Path`.

Comment: oh sorry my, bad its not terminal, but the RUN window in Intelij Idea

Comment: This works fine for me using JDK 20 with Intellij IDEA 2023.1.1 Preview (Ultimate Edition). Are you saying that everything worked until you upgraded from 16 to 20?

Comment: that's right, but when i switch back for example from the 20 to 16 then it works fine.

Comment: Try changing your code to call `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8"));` before calling `println()`. That should fix the problem for Java releases >= 18.

Comment: Try using the latest IntelliJ IDEA build from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-2100661425/IntelliJ-IDEA-2023.1-Latest-Builds

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I commented earlier that I couldn't reproduce the problem with 2023.1.1 Preview. However, my default charset is UTF-8. I think the issue only arises when `PrintStream.charset()` returns a value other than "UTF-8", so my confirmation didn't really prove anything.

Comment: The issue is documented in JetBeans bug report [Running the Java project by using the JDK 18 prints the garbled characters in console when try printing the non-ASCII characters in the code](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291006/Running-the-Java-project-by-using-the-JDK-18-prints-the-garbled-characters-in-console-when-try-printing-the-non-ASCII-characters). In JDK 18+ the encoding used by `PrintStream` (which is the system default encoding unless specified otherwise) and the encoding used by the console must match.

Answer (score 0):

Set the character encoding of your console to [UTF-8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). To change the default encoding of the console within IntelliJ, [see the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-console-folding.html#folding-patterns).

Then read [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: I think the problem probably arose precisely because the console encoding was set to UTF-8, but their default charset was not UTF-8. This issue only arises with JDKs >= 18, which explains why everything worked for the OP with JDK 16. Based on a comment to the question, it looks like the latest Intellij IDEA release resolves the issue.